# What are the different ways to set file permissions, etc., on GNU/Linux?

Tags: linux, permissions, filesystems, gnu

On Unix, a long time back, I learned about `chmod`:
the traditional way to set permissions on Unix
(and to allow programs to gain privileges, using setuid and setgid).

I have recently discovered some newer commands on GNU/Linux:

- `setfacl` extends the traditional `ugo:rwx` bits and the `t` bit of `chmod`.
- `setcap` gives more fine-grained control over privileges
  than the `ug:s` bits of `chmod`.
- `chattr` allows some other controls (a bit of a mix) over the file.

Are there any others?

Comment: see also https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/183994/4778 for more detail on `chmod`

Comment: see also https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/246606/4778 for extended ACLs (richACLs).

Answer (score 33, accepted):

## [`chmod`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/chmod): change file mode bits

Usage (octal mode):

  ```
  chmod octal-mode files...
  ```

Usage (symbolic mode):

  ```
  chmod [references][[operator][modes]] files...
  ```

*`references`* is a combination of the letters `ugoa`,
which specify which user's access to the *`files`* will be modified:

- `u` the user who owns it
- `g` other users in the file's group
- `o` other users not in the file's group
- `a` all users

If omitted, it defaults to all users,
but only permissions allowed by the `umask` are modified.

*`operator`* is one of the characters `+-=`:

- `+` add the specified file mode bits
  to the existing file mode bits of each *`file`*
- `-` removes the specified file mode bits
  from the existing file mode bits of each *`file`*
- `=` adds the specified bits and removes unspecified bits, except the `setuid` and `setgid` bits set for directories, unless explicitly specified.

*`mode`* consists of a combination of the letters `rwxXst`, which specify which permission bits are to be modified:

- `r` read
- `w` write
- `x` (lower case `X`) execute (or search for directories)
- `X` (capital) execute/traverse only if the file is a directory
  or already has an execute bit set for some user category
- `s` setuid or setgid (depending on the specified *`references`*)
- `t` restricted deletion flag or sticky bit

Alternatively, the *`mode`* can consist of one of the letters `ugo`,
in which case case the mode corresponds to the permissions
currently granted to the owner (`u`), members of the file's group (`g`)
or users in neither of the preceding categories (`o`).

### The various bits of `chmod` explained:

- Access control (see also `setfacl`)

  - `rwx` — read (`r`), write (`w`), and execute/traverse (`x`) permissions

    - Read (r) affects if a file can be read, or if a directory can be listed.
    - Write (w) affects if a file can be written to,
      or if a directory can be modified (files added, deleted, renamed).
    - Execute (x) affects if a file can be run,
      use for scripts and other executable files.
    - Traverse (x), also known as "search",
      affects whether a directory can be traversed;
      i.e., whether a process can access (or try to access) file system objects
      through entries in this directory.
  - `s` and `t` — sticky bit (`t`), and setgid (`s`) on directories

    - The sticky bit only affects directories. Will prevent anyone except file owner, and root, from deleting files in the directory.
    - The setgid bit on directories will cause new files and directories
      to have the group set to the same group,
      and new directories to have their setgid bit set
      (see also defaults in `setfacl`).
  - `s` — setuid, setgid, on executable files

    - This can affect security in a bad way, if you don't know what you are doing.
    - When an executable is run, if one of these bits is set,
      then the user/group of the executable
      will become the effective user/group of the process. 
      Thus the program runs *as* that user. 
      See `setcap` for a more modern way to do this.

---

## [`chown`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/chown) [`chgrp`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/chgrp):

---

## [`chattr`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/chattr): change file attributes

Usage:

  ```
  chattr operator[attribute] files...
  ```

*`operator`* is one of the characters `+-=`:

- `+` adds the selected attributes to be to the existing *`attributes`* of the *`files`*
- `-` removes the selected *`attributes`*
- `=` overwrites the current set of attributes the files have with the specified *`attributes`*.

*`attribute`* is a combination of the letters `acdeijmstuxACDFPST`,
which correspond to the attributes:

- `a` append only
- `c` compressed
- `d` no dump
- `e` extent format
- `i` immutable
- `j` data journaling
- `m` don't compress
- `s` secure deletion
- `t` no tail-merging
- `u` undeletable
- `x` direct access for files
- `A` no `atime` updates
- `C` no copy on write
- `D` synchronous directory updates
- `F` case-insensitive directory lookups
- `P` project hierarchy
- `S` synchronous updates
- `T` top of directory hierarchy

There are restrictions on the use of many of these attributes. 
For example, many of them can be set or cleared only
by the superuser (i.e., root) or an otherwise privileged process.

---

## [`setfattr`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/setfattr): change [extended file attributes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_file_attributes)

Usage (set attribute):

  ```
  setfattr -n name -v value files...
  ```

Usage (remove):

  ```
  setfattr -x name files...
  ```

*`name`* is the name of the extended attribute to set or remove

*`value`* is the new value of the extended attribute

---

## [`setfacl`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/setfacl): change file access control lists

Usage:

  ```
  setfacl option [default:][target:][param][:perms] files...
  ```

*`option`* must include one of the following:

- `--set` set the ACL of a file or a directory, replacing the previous ACL
- `-m`|`--modify` modify the ACL of a file or directory
- `-x`|`--remove`  remove ACL entries of a file or directory

*`target`* is one of the letters `ugmo` (or the longer forms shown below):

- `u`, `users` permission of a named user identified by *`param`,*
  defaults to file owner UID if omitted
- `g`, `group` permission of a named group identified by *`param`,*
  default to owning group GID if omitted
- `m`, `mask` effective rights mask
- `o`, `other` permissions of others

*`perms`* is a combination of the letters `rwxX`, which correspond to the permissions:

- `r` read
- `w` write
- `x` execute
- `X` execute only if the file is a directory or already has execute permission for some user

Alternatively, *`perms`* may be an octal digit (`0`-`7`) indicating the set of permissions.

---

## [`setcap`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/setcap): change [file capabilities](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/libs/security/linux-privs/kernel-2.2/capfaq-0.2.txt)

Usage:

  ```
  setcap capability-clause file
  ```

A *`capability-clause`* consists of a comma-separated list of [capability](http://linux.die.net/man/7/capabilities) names followed by a list of operator-flag pairs.

The available operators are `=`, `+` and `-`. The available flags are `e`, `i` and `p` which correspond to the *Effective*, *Inheritable* and *Permitted* capability sets.

The `=` operator will raise the specified capability sets and reset the others. If no flags are given in conjunction with the `=` operator all the capability sets will be reset. The `+` and `-` operators will raise or lower the one or more specified capability sets respectively.

---

## [`chcon`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/chcon): change file [SELinux security context](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Security_context)

Usage:

  ```
  chcon [-u user] [-r role] [-t type] files...
  ```

*`user`* is the SELinux user, such as `user_u`, `system_u` or `root`.

*`role`* is the SELinux role (always `object_r` for files)

*`type`* is the SELinux subject type

---

## [`chsmack`](http://schaufler-ca.com/description_from_the_linux_source_tree): change [SMACK](http://schaufler-ca.com/description_from_the_linux_source_tree) extended attributes

SMACK is Simplified Mandatory Access Control Kernel.

Usage:

  ```
  chsmack -a value file
  ```

*`value`* is the SMACK label to be set for the `SMACK64` extended file attribute

---

## [setrichacl](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/7-richacl/): change rich access control list

[richacl](https://lwn.net/Articles/661357/)s are a feature that will add more advanced ACLs.

Currently a work in progress, so I can not tell you much about them. I have not used them.

See also this question [Are there more advanced filesystem ACLs beyond traditional 'rwx' and POSIX ACL?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/246606/are-there-more-advanced-filesystem-acls-beyond-traditional-rwx-and-posix-acl)
and [man page](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/7-richacl/)

Comment: +1 If you added examples of each cmd's usage, this answer would be extremely useful, as a canonical answer we can reference down the road!

Comment: @slm Thanks for the suggestion. I added a brief usage explanation for each command.

Comment: A warning to any one wishing to take capabilities further than shown here. I have used capability as outlined here. However trying to inherit them (usefully) over fork and exec seems impossible. I think there is a bug see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/196483/how-do-i-use-capsh-i-am-trying-to-run-an-unprivileged-ping-with-minimal-capabi

Comment: The bug I mentioned in previous coment, it was a design bug and was fixed in kernel 4.3 with the addition of ambient capabilities, see http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html

Comment: I'd love to see examples on all this this would become a canonical answer !

Answer (score 1):

From a high level:

- Basic file system permissions supported by *all Linux*
  and *all* Unix-friendly *filesystems*
  which is the `-rwxrwxrwx` handled by `chmod`,
  along with owner and group identifiers
  tied to every file or folder on the filesystem handled
  by `chown` and `chgrp`; everyone basically knows this piece.
- **Extended File Attributes**, which is abbreviated or known by **xattr**. 
  They are file system features that enable users to associate files
  with metadata not interpreted by the filesystem,
  whereas regular attributes have a purpose strictly defined by the filesystem;
  the attributes are name:value pairs
  associated
  with files and directories,
  similar to the environment strings associated with a process. 
  There are specific Linux commands
  related to simply setting this metadata to various files/folders.
- **Security-Enhanced Linux** (commonly known as **SELinux**).
    
  See [selinuxproject.org](https://selinuxproject.org/page/Main_Page) and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security-Enhanced_Linux). 
  Also know there are alternatives to SELinux such as AppArmor,
  and probably others. 
  At this point,
  these are kernel modules that provide functionality and mechanisms
  for doing MAC (mandatory access control)
  **by making use of xattr; SELinux stores file security labels in xattrs**. 
  And there are specific SELinux-related commands.

Other key points:

- The era and version of GNU/Linux matters regarding `xattr`
  and SELinux for what is available and what is functional.
- It is reported that not all file systems support `xattr`;
  best left to individual research
  based on the distribution and version of Linux being used
  (RHEL/SUSE/Debian, IRIX, Solaris, AIX, Unix from the 1960s).
- It's really just the inherent basic file/folder permissions with UIDs/GIDs
  plus `xattr`s that makes everything possible;
  SELinux uses `xattr`s to store file/folder security labels...
  with SELinux all the low-level legwork
  is somewhat done/defined in `xattr`s for you to make use of. 
  So if your ancient file system does not support `xattr`,
  you won't be using SELinux.
- You can enable or disable SELinux
  (or AppArmor or any other kernel module).
- Depending on your version of Linux,
  you may be able to enable or disable `xattr`s
  for a given mounted file system;
  I remember in SLES 11 the `fstab` mount option of `user_xattr`
  and I could choose to not have `xattr` available on the root file system
  at install time; I think now with RHEL/CentOS 7
  that `xattr` is there by default and you can't remove it.
- When doing an `ls -l`, if you see `-rwxrwxrwx+`,
  that `+` indicates an extended file attribute is present on that object.
- **Access Control List** (ACL)
  is a list of permissions attached to an object. 
  An ACL specifies which users or system processes
  are granted access to objects,
  as well as what operations are allowed on given objects.
- **From the CentOS Wiki** article on **SELinux:**

  > SELinux is a MAC security mechanism implemented in the kernel.  ...  Without SELinux enabled, only traditional discretionary access control (DAC) methods such as file permissions or access control lists (ACLs) are used to control the file access of users.  Users and programs alike are allowed to grant insecure file permissions to others or, conversely, to gain access to parts of the system that should not otherwise be necessary for normal operation.  ...  Essentially under the traditional DAC model, there are two privilege levels, root and user, and no easy way to enforce a model of least-privilege.  Many processes that are launched by root later drop their rights to run as a restricted user ...

  worth the read to put the use of `xattr`s and ACLs in perspective, because Linux [kernel] treats everything as a file (block devices or network ports) you can tag almost anything with an `xattr` and enforce some kind of access control via SELinux; it's not just files/folders.  https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux
- `xattr` can cause problems with moving data between systems and file systems, and NFS, where [newer] systems having fuller support of `xattr` versus older systems which might not recognize all these extended attributes [if at all]. 
  Be mindful of using `tar` on stuff with `xattr`; if it stays on that system no problem but if it goes elsewhere can be problematic if the `xattr`s are important
  (e.g., Samba and copying between Windows 10 NTFS
  and Linux ext3/4, btrfs, XFS;
  or back and forth between network attached storage (NAS) devices).
- If there is no SELinux or other mechanism
  enforcing ACLs by what is defined in `xattr`s,
  then `xattr`s can theoretically mean nothing and be dropped or stripped,
  because at that point it's just extra baggage.
- Be careful *disabling* SELinux now in RHEL/CentOS 7
  because if file system labels via `xattr` are lost it will cause problems
  when changing SELinux back to *enforcing* or *permissive*;
  again it depends on your version of Linux
  and how it is making use of `xattr` via SELinux.

Basic Samba share not working in RHEL/CentOS 7... because SELinux by default is set to enforcing; SELinux denies everything until you allow it, so either disable SELinux (bad) or set it to permissive.  If you leave SELinux as enforcing, then you have to label the folder you want to Samba share out with an extended attribute, so SELinux will recognize and allow the share.  So if you leave SELinux enforcing then with all SELinux commands (which will then set the necessary `xattr`s):

```
# from CentOS 7.6 /etc/samba/smb.conf.example

# Turn the samba_domain_controller Boolean on to allow a Samba PDC to use
# the useradd and groupadd family of binaries.
# Run the following command as the root user to turn this Boolean on:

setsebool -P samba_domain_controller on

# If you create a new directory, such as a new top-level directory, label it
# with samba_share_t so that SELinux allows Samba to read and write to it.
# Do not label system directories, such as /etc/ and /home/, with samba_share_t,
# as such directories should already have an SELinux label.


# the xattr having the name "samba_share_t" is labelled onto "/mydatashare"
# this xattr of syntax "samba_share_t" is recognized by an existing rule in SELinux
# if the folder does not have the xattr "samba_share_t" then the rule in SELinux
# (when enforced) will prevent access via Samba to the folder.

chcon -t samba_share_t /mydatashare
```

You further use SELinux, on the Linux system with this Samba share,
to enforce restrictions on files/folders under this Samba share
(using whatever extended attribute). 
Because these files/folders are shared out,
a user legitimately copies some to their Windows 10 PC and then copies back,
losing the extended attribute. 
Now after that back and forth copy,
on that Linux system SELinux will restrict access to said files
because the necessary `xattr` is no longer present,
and users/admins bang their heads wondering why something just worked
and now it doesn't... 
Set SELinux to permissive
and recognize the problem of lost `xattr`s showing up in the audit logs
but it won't directly indicate it was a result of the back and forth copy losing the `xattr`. 
Also consider data backup and restoration,
and potential work needed to remember `xattr`s in addition to UID/GID
if you want to enforce security based on the correct `xattr`s.

Comment: I have noticed a lot a stray apostrophes in this post: E.g. uid's where it should be UIDs. (see https://ctrlaltdelor.wordpress.com/2014/01/09/a-single-rule-for-apostrophes/ for more on this. )

Answer (score -1):

I highly recommend chmod

$ chmod [Options] [Filename]

$ chmod [Option1] [Operator] [Option2] [Filename]

---

In numerical representation, we have these options:

“0” represents “no permission”

“1” represents “execute permission”

“2” represents “write permission”

“4” represents “read permission”

options in the symbolic form:

“u” indicates file owner

“g” indicates groups

“o” indicates others

“a” indicates all users as owner, group, and others (ugo)

Whereas the chmod command accepts the following operators:

“+”: This operator is utilized to add specified permissions

“–”: This operator is utilized to remove specified permissions

“=”: This operator is utilized to define the exact file permission for any user.

Comment: Read the other answers, then re-read the question. Your universe will get bigger. Mind did.