# UMASK privacy- how can I make user files private to the users

Tags: permissions, umask, privacy

I have a debian virtual machine set up and thought of something in regards to UMASK. First I would like to ask if the function of UMASK is to set CHMOD values on any file created by a user. Secondly, is there a way that UMASK can be used to effectively lock root out of files or is it the issue of root being "god" and able to unlock any files of lesser users? Would this be a scenario where it would make more sense for users seeking private files to instead have some type of virtual machine running inside debian to lock I as the admin out of their files?

Comment: Can you do it with access control lists? http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/101263/what-are-the-different-ways-to-set-file-permissions-etc-on-gnu-linux

Answer (score 1):

> if the function of UMASK is to set CHMOD values

`umask` is not the same as `chmod`. The process umask describes which permission bits will be automatically cleared when files are first created. It works like this:

```
actual permission = requested permission & ~umask
```

Typically, applications request permissions like `0666` for a regular file, and the umask might be, for example `027`. The result is `0640`. That `umask` says:

- don't clear any owner bits (`0`, binary `000`)
- force the writable-by-group flag off (`2`, binary `010`)
- force all permissions off for others (`7`, binary `111`)

The umask doesn't get consulted at all for operations like `chmod` which explicitly set all the permission bits.

> Secondly, is there a way that UMASK can be used to effectively lock root out of files

No. Nothing you do will prevent root from accessing any file...

> for users seeking private files to instead have some type of virtual machine running inside debian

...not even that. The root user on the hypervisor or dom0 (or similar, for other virtualization technologies) can still access anything on the system.