# Move file to another user's home directory (without sudo)?

Tags: permissions, scp, mv

I have a couple of files that I want to move to another's user home directory. I don't have permissions to write to that user's home directory, but I know his password.

I know how to *copy* the file using `scp` (see [here](https://superuser.com/a/353577/91054)). However, if I want to move the file, copying and then removing the original file is inefficient. Is there a way to *move* the file, without using `sudo` (I don't know the root's password)?

Comment: using `sudo` doesn't require the root p/w, but your own, as long as your user is in the `sudoer` group.

Comment: FYI, a move on the same filesystem is not copy then delete. A move just moves. It's only moves across filesystems that are simulated by copying and deleting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Subject to certain assumptions that the target user can actually access the file in its original location, the following approach could work:

```
SRC='/path/to/existing/file'
DST='/path/to/new/file'

su target_user sh -c "ln -f '$SRC' '$DST'" && rm -f "$SRC"
```

This "moves" the file to the new user's location, but does not change the ownership or permissions.

Comment: +1 This does link unlink (an implementation of move), as different users. So no write access of source files is needed by receiving user.

Comment: I want to move a full directory (along with its contents). I get an error: `ln: ‘$SRC’: hard link not allowed for directory`

Comment: This answers my original question. I asked about directories [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/287193/56755).

Answer (score 0):

You can `su` to any user, if you know there password. (for sudo you need to be a sudoer, and know your own password).

So make the files readable and directory writeable(for deletion) by the other user, add files to a shared group, or use access-control-lists (ACLs) `setfacl` ([What are the different ways to set file permissions etc on gnu/linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/101263/what-are-the-different-ways-to-set-file-permissions-etc-on-gnu-linux))

Then `su other user`
Then do the move.

---

Also look at @roaima 's answer for how to do it without giving write access away to receiving user.