# How to copy file to another user (have password, no root)?

Tags: linux, su, non-root-user

I am `user_a` and I have a password for `user_b`, so I can use `su user_b` to do things as `user_b`.

I want to copy a file from `user_a` to `user_b`.

I **don't** want other users besides `user_a` and `user_b` to see the file, and I don't have root on the machine.  So the usual trick of moving the file to /tmp is not acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use back to back tar to do the copy. For example

```
 tar cf - file1 file2 dir1/file3 | su user_b tar -C ~user_b/somewhere -xf -
```

This will create ~user_b/somewhere/file1 as a copy of file1. ~user_b/somewhere has to exist first. There are some limitations on the tar format, but you are unlikely to hit them.

If it is just a single file then

```
 su - user_b bash -c 'cat > ~user_b/file1' < file1
```

followed by adjusting the permissions might be less trouble.

Comment: I got a "permission denied" with the `cat` example, but the `ln` example worked for me from this answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/185826/57734