# Can you assign Linux capabilities to users?

Tags: linux, solaris, capabilities

In Solaris, I believe that you can assign privileges to users.

I know that in Linux you can assign capabilities to executable files, but can you also assign capabilities to users?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible to give additional capabilities to processes running as non-root users in Linux, which can be useful to allow these users to run a non-setuid `ping` binary, or to run servers that bind to a privileged port (< 1024).

In many cases, you will need [ambient capabilities](https://lwn.net/Articles/636533/) support for this to work correctly, so you might need to use a recent kernel and libraries to unlock all the features needed to make capabilities useful as a non-root user.

(You can also use inheritable capabilities, but that requires you to mark the binaries to be executed with matching file capabilities, using `setcap`.)

An example of using [capsh(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/capsh.1.html) to run a non-setuid ping as a non-root user would be:

```
sudo capsh --caps="cap_net_raw+eip cap_setpcap,cap_setuid,cap_setgid+ep" \
    --keep=1 --user=nobody --addamb=cap_net_raw -- \
    -c "./ping -c1 127.0.0.1"
```

Note that you need capsh and libcap version 2.25+ (for `--addamb`) and Linux kernel 4.3+ for the support of ambient capabilities. See [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/196483/281844) for more details (the source for the command above.)

Note that you need `sudo` for the command above (since only root can add capabilities) but by the time `ping` gets executed, the user has been dropped to "nobody", so `ping` itself never gets to run with full root privileges, only with cap_net_raw.

Another situation in which capabilities can be useful is to launch a daemon. For example, running an HTTP server on port 80, without having to launch it as root and have it drop privileges only after binding to the port.

systemd offers [directives for configuring capabilities](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#Capabilities) on service units, and it can also run a process as non-root by configuring an `User=` for the service. For the case of running processes as a non-root user with extra capabilities, you may need ambient capabilities support as well, which will require Linux kernel 4.3+.

Comment: You can also use inheritable capabilities, if you also mark the executable.

Comment: Users don't have capabilities, processes do.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor Updated the answer to include your suggestions... Thanks!!!