# Is there something like 'sudo' but give only one capability not real root?

Tags: networking, sudo, privileges, capabilities, setcap

I want to run a one-time web server on port 80, which I will never run again.

Is there something like 'sudo' that gives only temporary `CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE`, not real root, to a process? So that we don't have to use `chmod` or `setcap`.

Comment: I’m not sure this is satisfactory for you (it needs to run as root, before dropping capabilities and changing users), but [`capsh`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/303738/86440) allows you to construct a specific set of capabilities before starting a program.

Comment: fakeroot might be what you're searching for

Comment: a new project ( https://github.com/SamerW/RootAsRole )  seem to match your need

Comment: For a different method specific to binding a socket to a privileged port for non-root daemons, usually available on Debian-like OSes (but usually not packaged for RHEL-like OSes), there's [`authbind`](https://manpages.debian.org/authbind/authbind.1): transparently (LD_PRELOAD) loads an helper which replaces the bind() call by executing it through a forked suid root binary helper which will do the actual bind() on the shared (socket) file descriptor.