# Free or cheap shell (i.e., platform) to run a Linux C program with root privileges (raw socket)

Tags: linux, shell, root, c, socket

I'm working on a Linux C program that needs root privileges (raw socket). 
I would like to run it on a host located in the US (I am in EU) to compare results. Is there any free (or cheap) shell available online to do it?

P.S.
Any correction about my (first) post will be welcome.

Comment: You do not need root to get raw socket privilege, you can use capabilities. see  http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/101263/what-are-the-different-ways-to-set-file-permissions-etc-on-gnu-linux

Comment: Can I set capabilities if I am not root?

Comment: You need the set-capabilities-on-files capability. It is not safe to give this away without other restrictions. So you probably will need root to initially set it.

Answer (score 6):

[Google Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/compute/) allows you to provision a Linux VM in your chosen region which you can then ssh into with root privileges. It's [cheap](https://cloud.google.com/compute/pricing) and you can get $300 worth of usage as a free trial.

Answer (score 1):

A free account at [SageMath Cloud](https://cloud.sagemath.com) may fit your purpose.  My account allows me to upload/download programs and compile/run them on a Ubuntu box located in the USA.  The purpose of [SageMath.org](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/tutorial/index.html) is to provide free, open source math software.  The website is based on Python, but Python is not the only programming language available.  In particular, an interactive shell and a C compiler are available, but I don't know what libraries are available.

Comment: I'm trying this, it seems like what I was looking for, but can't find root password. Some pages suggest "sage" as password, but it doesn't work. I'm using web terminal.

Comment: I now notice on my SageMath Cloud settings and configuration page, external network access is unavailable (to me).  I don't know how to get access, which I think you will need.  Can't help with root password either.  Sorry about that.

Comment: At SMC, you can get unrestricted network access by buying a membership subscription. Still, it wouldn't help you with the socket, since it is behind a firewall. You also do not need to be root to open up a port above 1024.