# How to call chmod and preserve the SGID bit?

Tags: linux, permissions, chown, umask, setgid

I have the following directory structure:

```
+ public/
|-+ pics/
| |-- a
| `-- b
`-+ thumbs/
  |-- a
  `-- b
```

I would like all the files in the tree to be owned by `gallery:http` with `ug=rwX,o=` mode set.

The script which happens to create directories within `pics` and `thumbs` runs
as the `gallery` user. I set SUID/SGID bits on `public`, `pics` and `thumbs`.

Now the problem is that the `a` directory will get created with owners `gallery:http` as it should, but it won't have the `x` permission for the group. If I call `chmod`, I'll clear the SGID bit. (Strange behavior, but that
will really happen, likely because `http` is not the user-owner of the file.)

I can't call `chown` as non-root user to set mode first and then the owners.

The only solution seems to be to set `umask` to `ug=rwx,o=`, create all the directories and then either change the `umask` before I create any regular file, or create the regular files and then change their mode to `ug=rw,o=`.

Is there a better, less ugly solution which I don't see?

Comment: "If I call chown, I'll clear the SGID bit" You probably meant `chmod`. But that does not make any sense. A file or directory has the UID of the creating process as owner. So if you create a directory then you can set SGID afterwards on it.

Comment: What is your `umask` setting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can change the script it might be the easiest solution to change the `mkdir` calls to `mkdir --mode=770`.

If you cannot change the script then ACLs might help:

```
setfacl -m d:u::rwx,d:g::rwx,o::- pics thumbs
```

`umask` does not set executable permission on files. It never sets any permissions; it just prevents permissions from being set on file creation.

Comment: `mkdir --mode=770` is *precisely* what I haven't seen. Thanks, @Hauke!

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options:

- `chmod g+x a`
- change the umask
- use access control lists.

Yes you can set bits without clearing other bits. See first option. But to make it more automated, then do one of the following:

- Set umask to rwxr-x---, and have each user have a private default group (their primary group only belongs to them).
- Use access control lists: with these you can not only set permissions for multiple groups and users, you can also set defaults for directories (much like sgid, however not just the group, but also the mode). see setfacl, getfacl. see also [What are the different ways to set file permissions etc on gnu/linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/101263/what-are-the-different-ways-to-set-file-permissions-etc-on-gnu-linux)