# what does "chcon -t samba_share_t /path/to/share" do?

Tags: centos, samba

I am setting up a samba share and two shares that are identical one is accessible and one is not. Wile looking into what might solve the problem I saw this command. I can not find what it does though.

What does "chcon -t samba_share_t  /path/to/share" do?

To elaborate on this question why would I ever need to run this command on one share but not the other. Both shares were created the same, same user and same computer.

Comment: related answer that may be of help https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/101269/4778

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It changes the SELinux context of the specified path to `samba_share_t`. This would be necessary if you have SELinux in enforcing mode on your system and the path being referred to was not previously designated as a Samba share (via SELinux labeling).

Answer (score 4):

John's answer gives an excellent explanation of the second part of your question. To add to John's answer, the command broken down looks like this:

- `chcon` - Changes security context for files. You can read more about `chcon` [here](https://linux.die.net/man/1/chcon).
- `-t samba_share_t` - The `-t` is used to designate the target security context's type, which in this case, is `samba_share_t`.
- `/path/to/share/` is the file targeted for the `chcon` operation.

Comment: I ran this on one of my shares and it granted access to the share folder but not sub folders is there a way to apply it to all sub folders?

Comment: You can use the `-R` or `--recursive` parameter to operate on all files and sub-folders.