# Linux user Hierachy

Tags: linux, security, users

In short, I want to know if it is possible to create three users:

`user`, `lowp0`, `lowp1`

Where someone loged in as `user` can log into `lowp0` or `lowp1` without a password, but `lowp0` and `lowp1` should not be able to log in as anyone else.

---

Why?
The idea is to isolate an application because the `lowp0`, `lowp1` users will only have access to a few files.

Comment: As well as `sudo` and `ssh`. Consider that you **may** not need to change user. You can set permissions on a file so that another user can access/write to it. see https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/101263/4778

Comment: I think the conflict is resolved as I clearly stated the duplicate and removed one question as soon as someone told me where it would fit better?

Comment: What can I do to resolve the hold/deletion process?

Comment: As no one has linked to the duplicate, I will take your word for it, and have voted to re-open.

Comment: Just for the future, what should I do if I am not sure where to place a question?

Comment: Yes that is a problem, there was in the 1960 or earlier an idea to categorize by tag, as opposed to location (So you would put all questions on the same site, and tag them). However this idea seems to be lost to history. Hold on one moment, does this site not have tags. But alas we have forgotten how to use them, and instead have created sub-sites.

Answer (score 5):

By editing the `/etc/sudoers` configuration file, you can configure `sudo` to allow one user to run commands as another user. In particular, you can use `sudo` to allow one user to launch a shell as another user. For example, the following line allows `user` run `bash` as `lowp0`:

```
user ALL=(lowp0) /bin/bash
```

You should then be able to do something like the following:

```
user@host:~$ sudo -u lowp0 bash
lowp0@host:~$
```

You could also use the `su` command in place of `bash`:

```
user ALL=(lowp0) /usr/bin/su -l
```

To allow access to both users via both commands, you could add the following lines:

```
user ALL=(lowp0,lowp1) /bin/bash, /usr/bin/su -l
```

If you're running an SSH server, you could also add the public key of `user` to the `~/.authorized_keys` files of `lowp0` and `lowp1`. This should allow `user` to `ssh` into localhost as either of these users, e.g.:

```
user@host:~$ ssh lowp0@localhost
lowp0@host:~$
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try this ASAP and accept this if it works

Comment: I don't think there's ever need to run `su` under `sudo`. They both do essentially the same thing: change user / raise privileges. There's `sudo -s` and `sudo -i` to start a shell or a login shell. Besides, running `su -l` as `lowp0` will just ask for the root password and then change to root. Also, if you allow running an unrestricted shell, you might just allow every other command at the same time, so just `user ALL=(lowp0,lowp1) ALL` should do.

Comment: Is there a way to prevent logging in as user from e.g. lowp0 except using a password?

Comment: @mame98 I'm not sure what you mean. By default the `lowp0` user wouldn't be able to log in as the `user` user without the password for `user`.

Comment: Ideally I do not want to specify a password for user but still prevent the others from logging in as user...

Comment: @mame98 I'm not sure what you mean. How do you plan on authenticating as `user` if you don't want to set a password?