# Adding suid to a binary file

Tags: shell, zsh, setuid

My question is about `suid`! The logic behind that is to grant root permission when a privileged command is executed by a user. For example, `passwd` has such a feature.

```
$ ls -l /usr/bin/passwd 
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 54224 Aug 21  2017 /usr/bin/passwd
```

I have written a piece of code which opens a `zsh`. So, I manually add `suid` to my executable.

```
$ chmod u+s myzs
$ ls -l myzs
-rwsr-xr-x 1 mahmood mahmood  7360 Jul  6 21:34 myzs
```

However, when I run the binary, the shell opens for the current user (me) and not the root. What is the difference between my binary file and passwd? both have suid.

```
$ ./myzs 
% whoami                                                                                       
mahmood
```

Comment: If that could work, then there would be no point having root. Everyone would be root. See @nohillside's answer. You understanding (in your first paragraph), is very slightly off. But in an important way.

Comment: May be relevant https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/101263/what-are-the-different-ways-to-set-file-permissions-etc-on-gnu-linux

Answer (score 4):

From `man chmod`

```
   4000    (the set-user-ID-on-execution bit) Executable files with this bit set 
           will run with effective uid set to the uid of the file owner.
```

So you need to set the owner of the file to the user you want the binary to run under, e.g. by running

```
sudo chown root myzs
```

Comment: That operation is not permitted by user. I wonder how some documents and videos on the web show that a user can open a root shell. Are they fake?

Comment: @mahmood You need to be root to set file ownership to root, basically. Otherwise it would open quite a wide security hole (which running zsh as root probably does anyway but I hope you know what you are doing).

Comment: Yes I am intentionally trying to open a root shell from my account. As I said there are videos and documents that show this is possible. I am not sure if that is OS specific. For example, Kali may allow that!

Comment: @mahmood It will work once you have a setuided binary owned by root. The trick part is getting that binary.