# Linux File permissions for other user as root to read and execute

Tags: linux, permissions, nginx

I have a folder `/home/zain/uploads/hash/`

In `uploads` one of my service which is running with forever-service is creating `hash` folder and put file inside it ..

problem is, it is creating hash folder and file inside it as `root` user and 700 access since it is running with forever-service ..

But when I tried to access through my nginx so it give me `403 forbidden` ..

my nginx user is `opc` ..

If I change owner or group manually then I can access to that file.. so I don't want to change permissions manually every time.

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: How do you execute the forever-service? you should change the service user-id to be `opc`... or update it, to change the output files to be owned by `opc`

Comment: @Yaron `forever-service must be run as root` it give me this error when i tried to run with opc

Comment: Can you update the service runs by `forever-service` to execute `chown opc -R /home/zain/uploads/hash` and/or `chmod 755 -R /home/zain/uploads/hash` as its last steps?

Comment: @Yaron nopes i cant edit that script .. and also have a similar thought of creating cronJob which checks new entry of file and changes its permission ... but thats doesnt seems a right way..

Comment: cross-posting: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1063146/linux-file-permissions-for-other-user-as-root-to-read-and-execute

Comment: @Yaron it supports a "runasuser" option but this "function getForeverRoot(user){" https://github.com/zapty/forever-service/commit/58f0800f2a0ebccd8839f754b688debfaeeedc1c seems to look like getuid needs to be 0. I would assume that test needs to be done when user=null only :P Seems a bug to me

Answer (score 0):

I can see two options,

- Run the service as a different user, but use capabilities. `root` has been broken up in to many capabilities, if the service is written well (does not, un-necessarily, try to do security, but lets kernel do it), then it should work with capabilities.
- Use file access control lists, with defaults, so that the other user is added with read (maybe write) permissions.

See [What are the different ways to set file permissions etc on gnu/linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/101263/4778) for a list of ways that modern Linux does permissions.

Answer (score 0):

It may be sufficient to change the umask of the process creating the files.