# how can i make a file in /opt/ which will be owned by 2 users, 3 groups and other should not have any kind of access

Tags: linux, ubuntu, users

I want to know how I can make a file in `/opt/`, that will be owned by 2 users and 3 groups, and others should not able to access it.

Comment: A file has exactly one owner and one group. You may mean "can be accessed by two users and three groups". If this is an assignment, please give us the complete text so that the question will be clear.

Comment: Interestingly, https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/491492/ , asked a mere hour later, is talking about much the same goal with simply a different directory name.

Comment: You need file access control (`setfacl`). see https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/101263/4778

Answer (score 1):

ACL is another great way for access control.
In my opinion you can include your 2 users to a particular group and grant `chmod 770` to that `/opt` directory, where 0 means no privileges to others.

Comment: While that's a great suggestion, it's not an answer. A file in Linux **can't** have two owners.