# Keep access to a file after sudo

Tags: sudo, users, access-control

`user1` runs `sudo -u user2 SomeCommand`. I want `SomeCommand` to be able to access the files of `user1` (or just a specific directory or even a single file, if that's easier), without giving access to `user2` (a shared user everyone uses for running that command) in general. Are there any ways to achieve that?

Answer (score 3):

You have suggested 2 ideas in you question, so two solutions

- `setfacl`: to set file permissions. You can use this to set different file permissions for each user/group. see [What are the different ways to set file permissions etc on gnu/linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/101263/4778)
- `sudo --group user2` or `sudo --user user2 --group user1`: to give access to all files, but you will have to add group write (edit umask), and ensure that default group is personal group.