# How to change permissions of all the files in my directory?

Tags: permissions, chmod

I used a script to install Hadoop

```
/opt/hadoop-3.2.0$ ll
total 216
drwxr-xr-x 10 yarn hadoop   4096 јул  9 08:05 ./
drwxr-xr-x  9 root root     4096 јул  9 07:42 ../
drwxr-xr-x  2 yarn hadoop   4096 јан  8 08:59 bin/
drwxr-xr-x  3 yarn hadoop   4096 јан  8 07:13 etc/
drwxr-xr-x  2 yarn hadoop   4096 јан  8 08:59 include/
drwxr-xr-x  3 yarn hadoop   4096 јан  8 08:58 lib/
drwxr-xr-x  4 yarn hadoop   4096 јан  8 08:59 libexec/
-rw-rw-r--  1 yarn hadoop 150569 окт 18  2018 LICENSE.txt
drwxrwxr-x  2 yarn hadoop   4096 јул  9 08:05 logs/
-rw-rw-r--  1 yarn hadoop  22125 окт 18  2018 NOTICE.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1 yarn hadoop   1361 окт 19  2018 README.txt
drwxr-xr-x  3 yarn hadoop   4096 јан  8 07:13 sbin/
drwxr-xr-x  4 yarn hadoop   4096 јан  8 09:32 share/
```

Now I want to change the permissions

```
/opt/hadoop-3.2.0$ whoami
miki
```

My goal is that miki is the owner of all the files in hadoop-3.2.0.
I guess I should use chmod?
How should the command look like?

Comment: Till depth 1 or for subdirectories also?

Comment: I think that should suffice.

Comment: This may be of help https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/101263/4778

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the only the owner for all files recursively (this means all files in subdirectories get also changed):

```
sudo chown -R miki /opt/hadoop-3.2.0
```