# mount with umask does not works

Tags: permissions, mount, umask, nvme

I tried to run

`mount /home/user/nvme0n1 -U 8da513ec-20ce-4a2d-863d-978b60089ad3 -t ext4 -o umask=0000`

and the response is:

> mount: `/home/user/nvme0n1`: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock
>   on `/dev/nvme0n1`, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.

However, when I remove the `umask` option, the SSD is mounted as desired. 
What should I do? How can I start debugging the problem? I want the device to have mode=777.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're mounting an ext4 filesystem:

`... -t ext4 -o umask=0000`

Per [the `ext4(5)` man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/ext4.5.html), the ext4 filesystem does not have a `umask` mount option.

> I want the device to have mode=777.

If you need different permissions on files and/or directories, you can set file/directory permissions on the files/directories themselves.  See
[**What are the different ways to set file permissions etc on gnu/linux**](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/101263/what-are-the-different-ways-to-set-file-permissions-etc-on-gnu-linux).

Comment: Thanks!
So if you chmod the directories to be 777, it will appears in boot (assuming we add the corresponding entry to fstab)?

Comment: @user3563894 It should be persistent.  Just make sure you change the permissions after the file system is mounted.  If you change the mountpoint permissions with the file system **not** mounted, things can get confusing after you mount the filesystem.