# Can't rsync to www-data owned directory

Tags: permissions, rsync, users, nginx

I have a ubuntu 18.04 server running on GCP (nginx+php7). I've setup a directory `/var/www/mysite.com` which is `drwxr-xr-x  www-data:www-data`. `public_html/` is also `drwxr-xr-x www-data:www-data`.

I'm using the following command to try to rsync the files to the directory (for automated deployment):

```
rsync -azvp test/ me@xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:/var/www/mysite.com/public_html/test/
```

However, when I do this, I get the following error:

```
rsync: mkdir "/var/www/mysite.com/public_html/test" failed: Permission denied (13)
```

I've checked `groups` of the `me` user and it is part of the `www-data` group.

Why am I still getting permission denied even though i'm part of the www-data group? I'm starting to wonder if I'm even using the correct group for what i'm trying to do.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3):

Group `www-data` does not have write permission.

( you state it has permissions `drwxr-xr-x  www-data:www-data` )

You need to (at least) give write permission to this group (`sudo --user www-data chmod -R g+w /var/www/mysite.com`).

In addition I would consider using file access control lists (with default permissions), to ensure that group `www-data` retains access. see [What are the different ways to set file permissions etc on gnu/linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/101263/4778) for more info on this.