# Permissions Issue on Debian with Apache Server

Tags: debian, permissions, apache-httpd

I know there is a ton of questions like this on here. I have looked at, I feel like, all of them and tried the solutions. However I have been running into this issue for a while now.

I have a user that is part of the www-data group.  We will call him userA.  On my server I have folders setup as Production and Testing.  Both are owned by root:www-data.

```
drwxr-sr-x 2 root www-data 4096 Jan 14 17:25 production
```

Now with the above directory, in order for me to add files I have to chown to userA:www-data, and then back to root:www-data, once i complete the updates.

userA is part of www-data group

```
userA: userA adm www-data
```

I was under the impression that if a user is part of the group he would be allowed to edit and add files and directory.  What am I missing here?

Comment: The group does not have write permissions on the folder. Just `chmod g+w -R /path/to/folder`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @PiotrP.Karwasz says no write permission for the group.

Solutions (one of):

- give write permission to the group: `chmod g+w -R /path/to/folder`
- give write permission to the user: as you did, but don't switch it back.
- give write permission to (possibly many) additional users/groups: using `setfacl` see  [What are the different ways to set file permissions etc on gnu/linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/101263/4778)

Comment: Thank you!! That worked for me