# How to provide full access to specified directory?

Tags: linux, permissions

How to provide full access only to specified directory (`/home/new_user/`) which contains php-executable files which user can execute?

The user can't change directory :

```
ls -la /home
```

results in the error message "You haven't permissions"

Comment: What have you tried? What did not work? You are correct that `chmod 777` will do it (However it is over kill, that gives permission to all users). Think about who the person is logged in as (what `user`?).
Then configure it the same as if they were logged in via other means e.g. via console, or X11. It is exactly the same.

Comment: The bit at the end of your question "User can't see any other directories." is that a statement or another question. If another question, then it should be in another question. If a statement, then it needs elaborating (what does it mean?). Please edit question to resolve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out ACLs (Access Control Lists), they allow finer grained access control than the rough owner-group-others Unix model. Not all filessytems handle them, though.

Comment: see https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/101263/4778 for more on permissions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setfacl` command for a specific folder and user.

for user;

```
sudo setfacl -Rm d:u:new_user:rwx /home
```

for group;

```
sudo setfacl -Rm d:g:new_user:rwx /home
```

for check permissions;

```
getfacl /home
```