# Enable symbolic link from other user

Tags: permissions, symlink

I'm trying to get the symbolic link from other user.

My file is located in `/home/serviceA/logs/a.txt` And I want to create a symbolic link to `/home/centos/logs/a.txt`.

Here is my command I ran as root user:
`ln -s /home/serviceA/logs/a.txt /home/centos/logs/a.txt`

I see the red color of filename. And I still get the permission denied error

The error is `lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 47 Feb 12 01:49 hi.txt -> /home/rundeck/ServiceDelivery/promo_logs/hi.txt`

Eventually, I want to forward the `/home/centos/logs/a.txt` log file to the Splunk.

Why am I getting the permission error after creating the symbolic link? And how do I fix it? (`chmod 777` didn't help)

Comment: "The error is". Why does the "error" not relate to the earlier command? The command shows different file names. What you need to show is the `ls -l` output for the correct files
: `/home/serviceA/logs/a.txt` and  `/home/centos/logs/a.txt`,

Comment: This question is a little weird and the comment above is relevant, your file names do not match. Also, different directories in /home almost always belong to different users (each user's home directory), so you need to see the permissions. On my system, my home directory is rwx------ meaning only I (and root) can even look inside. The reason for this is obvious (user privacy) and is likely common across different platforms. Are you attempting this as root?

Comment: I reposted my problem here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/567242/how-to-sync-home-usera-transfer-and-home-userb-transfer/567252?noredirect=1#567252. Please help if you can please

Comment: to or from. I am confused as to what you are trying to do. This is probably why you can not do it. There also seems to be confusion over what an error message is.

Answer (score 2):

First the file that you link to **must** be accessible to the user that will read it. The symlink will not add accessibility.

Then you do:
`ln -s -T existing-file name-of-the-link`

If the file-name will be the same, but in different directories, then you can also do:
`ln -s -t directory-where-you-want-the-link existing-file`

If you need to add accessibility, then one of these may help:

- ACLs (see [What are the different ways to set file permissions etc on gnu/linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/101263/4778))
- bind mount