# How to sync /home/userA/transfer and /home/userB/transfer?

Tags: symlink

How to sync /home/userA/transfer and /home/userB/transfer?

I tried to make a symlink.
`ln -s /home/userA/transfe /home/userB/transfer`

Symlink doesn't work...

```
lrwxrwxrwx   1 centos  centos   40 Feb 12 19:55 transfer -> /home/userB/transfer
```

Comment: what do you really want to do ? synchronize or build a symlink ??

Comment: @francoisP what I want is to sync the file under the directory; And my approach was making a symlink.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Home directories of user are picky about access of other users.
Everything down the home dir is supposed to be owned by user of that home.
You are probably facing permission issues, thus symlinks are definitely a wrong way. If you do not want a real-time synching and only make sync from time to time,
you should have permissions to access both dirs, most probable option is be able to become a superuser. 
Then you can perform the sync and restore the natural ownership.
Here is way you can go:

```
id userB  # figure out the group of the userB, suppos the output is groupB
sudo -i   # become a superuser
rsync  -aP /home/userA/transfer/ /home/userB/transfer/ #sync using rsync
chown -R userB.groupB /home/userB/transfer # restore ownership
```

If that works for you, it can be optimized to non-interactive one-line command:

```
sudo bash -c "rsync -a /home/userA/transfer/ /home/userB/transfer/ && chown -R userB.$(id -gn userB) /home/userB/transfer/"
```

*UPDATE* an example:

```
→ sudo ls -al /home/joker/trans/
total 8
drwxrwxr-x. 2 joker joker 4096 Feb 12 20:44 .
drwx------. 9 joker joker 4096 Feb 12 20:33 ..
-rw-rw-r--. 1 joker joker    0 Feb 12 20:33 file1
-rw-rw-r--. 1 joker joker    0 Feb 12 20:33 file2

→ sudo ls -al /home/vagrant/trans/
total 8
drwxrwxr-x. 2 vagrant vagrant 4096 Feb 12 20:33 .
drwx------. 4 vagrant vagrant 4096 Feb 12 20:34 ..
-rw-rw-r--. 1 vagrant vagrant    0 Feb 12 20:33 file1

→ sudo bash -c "rsync -aP /home/joker/trans/ /home/vagrant/trans/ && chown -R vagrant.$(id -gn vagrant) /home/vagrant/trans"
sending incremental file list
./
file2
              0 100%    0.00kB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#1, to-chk=0/3)
```

Here trans subdir of user joker is synced to user vagrant
Try to reproduce with you users and see the difference.
(joker has sudo rights)

(*) Mind trailing slashes in rsync commands, they are important

Comment: id userB prints "uid=1274(userB) gid=1274(userB) groups=1274(userB),994(docker)"

Comment: What should we put for groupB? (`chown -R userB.groupB /home/userB/transfer # restore ownership`)

Comment: userB, as  gid=1274(userB) says

Comment: `chown -R userB.1274 /home/userB/transfer`?

Comment: chown -R userB.userB /home/userB/transfer

Comment: `ls -al` command in `/home/userA/transfer` doesn't print anything... :( Do you need any info?

Comment: you did your best... it gave me an idea.. at least

Comment: I assumed the direction of sync is A to B
what is yours?
Please see example in the update ..

Comment: both of them are mine? I'm in the same instance. I log in to userB as `sudo su userB`

Comment: `skipping directory .` this was the output

Comment: `sending incremental file list
./` and done

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104385/discussion-between-hellofanengineer-and-tagwint).

Comment: Accepted your answer. This is WORKING. THANKS A LOT