# SSH - restrict access to only one directory

Tags: debian, ssh, chroot, access-control

I want to have a user to be able to login with ssh, but only be able to read files from a specific directory.

I did some research. Is it true that this is only possible with chroot and home directories?

Running Debian 10.

Comment: Does it matter if they can read system programs (the stuff that is already published on the inter-web)?

Comment: you mean stuff like the top command. no I just dont want that it can read see or do anything to other directories.

Comment: So not write to other directories, not read "secret" information from other directories? If so then you need to use a separate user account, and file-permissions. see https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/101263/4778

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done this recently with restricted bash (rbash). https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Restricted-Shell.html
One of it's restrictions: `Changing directories with the cd builtin.`

Set user's default shell to `/bin/rbash` and directory to the directory that you wan't to limit him to in `/etc/passwd` and he will not be able to `cd` out of it.

Alternatively you could add an alias in the user's shell profile file: `alias cd='printf ""'`

Comment: I just tried `rbash`. It doesn't allow me to `cd` to a directory outside the initial directory but it doesn't restrict the access to files as an argument to commands, e.g. using `cat ../somefile`. I can even start an unrestricted `bash`. As written in the documentaition of `rbash`, you need additional means to really restrict the environment.

Comment: adding aliases to `.bash_profile` will prevent that. You can also prevent certain options for a command by creating a script checking if input has `/` and add that script via an alias. Example `alias cat='./checkforabsolutepaths.sh'`. All other commands that you might not want the user to have access to can be turned of with `alias cd='printf ""'`. Don't forget to remove write permissions from `.bash_profile` though.

Comment: These are some examples for what I wrote: "you need additional means to really restrict the environment". If you use `alias cat='./checkforabsolutepaths.sh'` you have to prevent the user from using `command cat` to call the command instead of the alias.

Comment: Also bypassed by specifying the command to run in the SSH invocation: `ssh host cat ../somefile` or even better: `ssh host bash`. As @Bodo said: "you need additional means to *really* restrict the environment."