# Prevent Users From Deleting Each Other Files Even They Have Full Rights of directory

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have a shared directory at `/` with access 777. So all my users can create  files in it. But I want to prevent users from deleting each others files. Any way to do it. I remember something about a setting special bit but can't really remember what exactly it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set the sticky bit:

```
chmod 1777 directory
```

`/tmp` is a folder with that behaviour.

Comment: It worked. Thanks

Comment: Also see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/101263/what-are-the-different-ways-to-set-file-permissions-etc-on-gnu-linux