# Grant two users to write and read in a virtual serial port

Tags: linux

I have two users mix and www-data (an apache server). I want that these two users have permissions to read and write in the Virtual Serial Port  /dev/pts/3, i created this virtual port following this tutorial https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52187/virtual-serial-port-for-linux.

So I added these two users to the group serial:

```
sudo adduser www-data serial
sudo adduser mix serial
```

and I granted access to the group to /dev/pts/3

```
sudo chgrp serial testdir
```

and I added 775 permission to /dev/pts/3

I'm able to write and read with the user mix but I can't write with the user www-data. Am I doing something wrong?

EDIT:

I restarted my apache server and now it works

Comment: Group membership is actually per _process_, not per user. The thing about "adding a user to a group" is a simplification. It only means that when the user logs in, the process started in their name is given the group memberships implied by those membership settings. (The group membership propagates down to child processes then.) So, two things: 1) if your HTTP server was running when you changed the config, the running process will not be affected by the change; and 2) depending on how it's started, the group memberships it gets may or may not be set based on the same rules

Comment: which Linux distribution are you running?

Comment: ubuntu 20.04, so i need to restart the apache server

Comment: Consider also access control lists `setfacl`. see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/101263/what-are-the-different-ways-to-set-file-permissions-etc-on-gnu-linux

Comment: lol I restart my apache server and know it works